# ¿Cómo asignarle una imagen individual a cada elemento de un listview en Android?

Tags: android

El problema es el siguiente: tengo una lista de categorías en una tabla de SQL Server con esta estructura:

CATEGORIA
- id
- codigo
- nombre

Con listar esos datos no tengo problema, la situación es que quiero colocarle una imagen significativa a cada categoría. Ejemplo, una gaseosa a la Categoría bebidas, pero no tengo ninguna referencia a esa imagen en la base de datos. Eso se puede hacer? y si se puede, alguien podría darme una idea de cómo hacerlo.

Gracias

Comment: Imagino que las categorías serán únicas y no se repetirán. No habrá dos con el mismo código o nombre. Así que puedes establecer una relación en tu código entre el código de la categoría y una imagen identificada por un nombre. Si la categoría es bebidas, usas la imagen bebidas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocar otra variable, donde colocar la ruta de la imagen que quuieres para cada categoria. Por ejemplo:
CATEGORIA - id - codigo - nombre - rutaImagen

Ya que como sabras en una basae de datos no puedes insertar las imagenes pero si la ruta donde estaran.